# How close to birth does "at birth" indicate?

Tags: meaning

I had a twin brother who died as a result of complications during delivery and lack of necessary hospital equipment. When someone asks, I never know how to correctly phrase this.

My twin died:

- at birth (This feels contradictory).
- while being born (again contradictory, dying while being born).
- while our mom was giving birth to us.

  ...

Would *at birth* cover perinatal death, or does it mean *while being born*?

Comment: *He died within hours of being born. He died shortly after his birth. He was only  a newborn when he died. He died in the first week of life...* there are many alternatives, it depends on how precise you want to be, see this website: https://www.babycentre.co.uk/a1014779/coping-with-the-loss-of-a-newborn-baby I agree though that the term *stillborn* implies something quite different.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think your suggested sentences are pretty close. Thanks.

Comment: I think died at birth is accurate and is different than stillborn.

Comment: "My twin died at birth" is perfectly acceptable. You have no obligation to further explain.

Comment: I think it depends on your definition of death. For instance in most cases time of death is only officially determined by a medical professional, however it is possible someone has died in prior to that determination.

Comment: I have no idea if this helps you in any way, but for medical records, most countries record that as a still birth.

Comment: It's somewhat funny that you argue the incorrectness of "at birth", but at the same time still describe your brother to have died **during delivery**. Both mean the same thing (delivery by the mother = birth of the baby); yet you only consider one of them wrong.

Comment: @Flater If you read the question more carefully, you'll realize that that's exactly why I posted this question. Because I don't know how to correctly describe the incident.

Answer (score 2):

Under the circumstances, "died shortly after birth" would probably keep it brief and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The medical term is **perinatal.**

*My brother suffered a perinatal death.*

:occurring in, concerned with, or being in the period of the time around birth. [Webster's]

This is different from *stillborn*, generally meaning the fetus never took a breath of air. These children have usually died a few days before delivery and the uterus expels them whether full term or not.

A *nuchal cord* for instance, when the umbilical cord wraps around the fetal neck enough to strangulate, can occasionally result in death in which it would be ambiguous of how otherwise to categorize besides *perinatal.*

There are also many conditions in which the child is born in a condition not compatible with life such as encephaloceles. However, these children can live for several days, months, or even years, as in the case of Tay-Sachs Disease. It is unclear where *perinatal* ends and *infancy* begins.